# Copy the last day of month and add it to the end in netcdf file with nco

Tags: concatenation, nco

I am working in nco and came across this difficult problem. I have to rearrange a 360 day calender into the normal gregorian calender of 365 days. In the 360 day calender each month has 30 days. My idea was to add one day to a month that should consist of 31 days in the gregorian calender and remove one or two days from February (leap or non-leap year). I know how to remove days (simply by copying what you need into another file with ncks).

Is there a simple way to copy the last day of a specific month and add it to the same month in the end?

My files are ranging through a year with 3hr resolution and I want to work with the variable called `tas` (temperature). Below I have ncdump'ed the most important part:

```
dimensions:
rlon = 424 ;
rlat = 412 ;
time = UNLIMITED ; // (2880 currently)

variables:
double rlon(rlon) ;
    rlon:standard_name = "grid_longitude" ;
    rlon:long_name = "longitude in rotated pole grid" ;
    rlon:units = "degrees" ;
    rlon:axis = "X" ;
double rlat(rlat) ;
    rlat:standard_name = "grid_latitude" ;
    rlat:long_name = "latitude in rotated pole grid" ;
    rlat:units = "degrees" ;
double time(time) ;
    time:standard_name = "time" ;
    time:units = "days since 1949-12-01 00:00:00" ;
    time:calendar = "360_day" ;
    time:long_name = "time" ;
    time:axis = "T" ;
float tas(time, rlat, rlon) ;
    tas:grid_mapping = "rotated_pole" ;
    tas:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
    tas:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
    tas:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
    tas:long_name = "Near-Surface Air Temperature" ;
    tas:units = "K" ;
    tas:coordinates = "lon lat height" ;
    tas:cell_methods = "time: point" ;
```

I am looking forward to hear ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by a longer method. First I split the yearly files into months. For each month I added and removed necessary days and then concatenated the resulting months.

If anyone has a faster method please share

Answer (score 1):

If the 360 day data are stored in twelve monthly files, then you can use the ncrcat record append [feature](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#rec_apn) along with negative hyperslab indices to count backwards from the end and append the last record to itself

```
ncrcat --rec_apn -d time,-1 in.nc in.nc
```

Be sure to back-up your data first as this overwrites the input.